# Concurrency issue in job-based system

Tags: concurrency, distributed-system

### Setup

Say I have a database table called `Events` which contains events for when a user becomes active or inactive

```
EventId|Timestamp     |User|Status  |
-------|--------------|----|--------|
1      |11/03/20 04:34|A   |ACTIVE  |
2      |11/03/20 05:11|A   |INACTIVE|
3      |11/03/20 05:15|A   |ACTIVE  |
4      |11/03/20 05:44|A   |ACTIVE  |
5      |11/03/20 06:15|A   |INACTIVE|
```

And another table called `StatusTransition` which keeps track of when the `Status` changes for a certain user, this links two items from the `Events` table (basically a *"start"* event and a corresponding *"end"* event). The goal here is to track the durations of when a user was active or inactive.

```
Id|StartEventId|EndEventId|
--|------------|----------|
1 |1           |2         |
2 |2           |3         |
3 |3           |5         |
```

The process whenever the application receives an event is to:

1. Write the record in the `Events` table. Call this `Record A`.
2. Fetch the most recent record (the one before Record A was written, assume there is always at least one) in the `Events` table for that user. Call this fetched record `Record B`.
3. If `Record B` has a different `Status` value from `Record A` then write an entry to the `StatusTransition`.

### Problem

The system that does the above is supposed to be designed as a job-based distributed system, in this case I have multiple worker applications being fed from a job queue.

Since there are multiple applications which might handle the two distinct events from the same user, it will be a problem if the events were written out-of-order.

Example:

- Some external application publishes two events to the job queue
- Worker A receives an event with a 11/03/20 04:54 timestamp
- Worker B receives an event with a 11/03/20 04:52 timestamp
- Worker A writes a `StatusTransition` record, linking this event and some other past event whereas it should be linked to the event Worker B received (but isn't written yet)

### Question

How do I design this such that it still yields the correct behavior even if workers process events out-of-order? (e.g. like separating the logic that writes to `StatusTransition` as another job, locking the `Events` table while writing to `StatusTransition`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Your `StatusTransition` table is complicating things without adding value. If you add a `PrevEventId` column to the `Events` table, everything you need is in that table. You can also add a duration field there and fill it just when you insert a new event.

To handle out-of-order events, the worker jobs need to check whether a newer `Event` entry exists when they want to insert their entry, and adjust the existing entry accordingly. This needs to be done in a database transaction, with an appropriate retry mechanism for when the transaction fails due to a concurrent conflicting insert.

Update: it just occurred to me that if you record duration in the event table, it might be more reasonable to have it in the initial entry, and have a column `NextEventId` that's being filled when a new entry is added.

Comment: The `StatusTransition` table was supposed to be a *Layer 2* table, it's a simplified table for the consumption of external systems which shouldn't define how the events are interpreted. Here I only write to `StatusTransition` if the `Status` actually changes, so it doesn't make sense to have a `Duration` field in the `Event` table directly.

Comment: You can handle out-of-order events even with the `StatusTransition` table if you do it in a database transaction, it just gets a bit more complicated. You always need to check for preceding and following events and update stuff when you detect out-of-order sequences.

Answer (score 0):

As the `Events` table is the single source of truth (TM), you should not rely on the derived table to be always perfect. Simply rebuild it instead.

In your case: when worker B writes its 4:52 event, it should check afterwards if there are any newer events. It will find that event id 6 has been written previously with a newer timestamp. Thus, delete everything from the transition table which contains event 6 and build up anew in the correct order.

Or alternatively, don't even do that in a worker, but in a batch which runs every once in a while and sets up the correct transitions according to current knowledge. That depends on your timing requirements.

Comment: `Simply rebuild it instead.`

This was also my initial thought, however I'm expecting a large amount of events (probably as high as 10/sec/user) so I do not know yet if this is the right thing to do. I imagine it would be quite computationally expensive to recalculate the entire table for a user if an out-of-order event comes in.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, you have to check for out-of-order inserts on every event if you want your `StatusTransition` table to be consistent all the time. If that's not necessary (i.e. if you only need it for a daily accounting job) by all means don't bother and just build it in batch when needed.